# Good, simple configuration library for large c++ project?

Tags: c++, user-interface, configuration

We are developing a rather large project in C++, where many components require configuration parameters. We would like to use a central place to configure everything (like a registry), preferably with a nice and simple GUI (e.g. like Firefox's `about:config`) and a simple API.

I am pretty sure this that many applications have this kind of problem, but could not find any libraries available that can be readily used for this. Does anyone know of a good (preferably free) library to use for this?

This should work cross platform in Windows and Linux.

Comment: If your projects is a windows project, is there a reason not to use the registry? Or is it cross platform?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[boost::program_options](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_38_0/doc/html/program_options.html) provides unified (and cross platform) support for configuration from command line, environment variables and [configuration files](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_38_0/doc/html/program_options/overview.html#id3763008).  It seems like it ought to scale to multiple bits of a large software system registering an interest in various parameters (e.g [option groups](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_38_0/doc/html/program_options/howto.html#id3763728)).  Not much help with the GUI or persistence side of things though (but then what's wrong with editing a config file with a text editor ?).

Comment: It sorta-kinda- fits the "simple" requirement. And I wouldn't say it's "good", more like "ugly" (cf. "The good the bad and the ugly"), but it does the job.

Answer (score 3):

I've used libconfig before, works well easy and LGPL.
http://www.hyperrealm.com/libconfig/

Comment: I've used that and found leak issues. After download latest version, still leaking.

Answer (score 0):

I've used a modified version of [John Torjo](http://torjo.com/) code from [TechRepublic/DDJ](http://www.ddj.com/cpp/202101554) ([source](http://software.techrepublic.com.com/abstract.aspx?docid=80071))

Answer (score 0):

The [multi platform](http://www.cs.wustl.edu/~schmidt/ACE-versions-i.html) [ACE](http://www.cs.wustl.edu/~schmidt/ACE.html) library has a [configuration](http://www.dre.vanderbilt.edu/Doxygen/Stable/ace/classACE__Configuration.html) class that uses config files that have the *Windows .ini* format.

Answer (score 0):

I've often used a simple wrapper around [pugxml](http://code.google.com/p/pugixml/). I find that creating a configuration class with parameter validation for enumerated types and so on makes the rest of the code much cleaner. If you are just dealing with key/value pairs you will have to validate the data all throughout your code. By writing a custom class for each application you can put all that in one place.

Answer (score 0):

Try Configurator. There is no GUI, but it's easy-to-use and flexible C++ library for configuration file parsing (from simplest INI to complex files with arbitrary nesting and semantic checking). Header-only and cross-platform. Uses Boost C++ libraries.

See: http://opensource.dshevchenko.biz/configurator